# How to display output in a custom format using Format-Custom, in PowerShell scripting?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet

```
Get-CIMInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | Select-Object Name, @{label="IPAddress";expression={($_.comment | Select-string -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.value}}
```

The above command gives me the following output:

```
Name                          IPAddress      
----                          ---------      
Webex Document Loader         100.100.100.100
OneNote (Desktop)             111.111.111.111
Microsoft XPS Document Writer 120.120.120.120
Microsoft Print to PDF        123.123.123.123
Fax                           127.127.127.127
```

I'm looking for some cmdlet that can be piped into the above command so that I can customize the output into the following:

```
Webex Document Loader(100.100.100.100), OneNote (Desktop)(111.111.111.111), Microsoft XPS Document Writer(120.120.120.120), Microsoft Print to PDF(123.123.123.123), Fax(127.127.127.127)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **PowerShell Core 7.0** this can be done using [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string):

```
Get-CIMInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | 
    Select-Object Name, @{label="IPAddress";expression={($_.comment | Select-string -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.value}} |
    Join-String -Property { '{0}({1})' -f $_.Name, $_.IPAddress } -Separator ', '
```

The `Join-String` cmdlet is used to both format and join the input objects into a single string. Parameter `-Separator` should be self-explanatory. The argument for `-Property` specifies a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) that defines a script block which formats the input object. The [format  operator `-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) is used to cleanly produce the desired format. Alternatively it could be done using string interpolation only, e. g. `"$($_.Name)($($_.IPAddress))"` but I don't like all the parenthesis.

---

Alternative solution for **PowerShell versions older than 7.0**, that don't provide `Join-String`:

```
(Get-CIMInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | 
    Select-Object Name, @{label="IPAddress";expression={($_.comment | Select-string -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.value}} |
    ForEach-Object {'{0}({1})' -f $_.Name, $_.IPAddress}) -join ', '
```

Here the [`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f) is used to produce a single one-line string. The [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#grouping-operator--) is used to turn the pipeline into an expression that collects all output into an array that the `-join` operator can take as its left-hand-side argument.

Comment: Thankyou @zett42 for your timely help. Your answer, really helped me out.